# Least upper bound for the maximum of two random variables

Tags: probability, inequality, expected-value, upper-lower-bounds

Two independent random variables are not negative and E[X]=a, E[Y]=b. We define a new random variable Z=max{X,Y}. If t>0 and t>max{a,b} calculate the best (least) upper bound for the probability P[Z>t].

Is it E[Z]=a*b?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know that the variables are independent, which means $$P(Z\leq t)=P(X\leq t \wedge Y\leq t)=P(X\leq t)P(Z\leq t),$$
or equivalently
$$P(Z>t)=1-(1-P(X>t))(1-P(Y>t)).$$
So use Markov's inequality to get bounds on $P(X>t)$ and $P(Y>t)$ and combine these to get a bound on $P(Z>t)$. This will be the best you can do, since it is possible for Markov's inequality to be tight for both $X$ and $Y$ (for a specific value of $t$).

Comment: $1-P(X\gt t)\gt 1-\frac{a}{t}$ and $1-P(Y\gt t)\gt 1-\frac{b}{t}$ so $(1-P(X\gt t)*(1-P(Y\gt t)\gt \frac{(t-a)*(t-b)}{t^2}$

Comment: thus $P(Z>t) < 1-\frac{(t-a)*(t-b)}{t^2} = (ab-at-bt)/t^2$

Answer (score 0):

The answer is $P(Z>t) < \frac{at+bt-ab}{t^2}$